# Element Intent-Filter is not closed?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an issue, the Android Manifest keeps coming back with a error saying "Element Intent-filter is not closed"

Heres my Android Manifest code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/_saintbedes3"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".event"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_event" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.event" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".news"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_news" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.news" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".parent"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_parent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.parent" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".contact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
        <intent-filter> //<- This is the error
             <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.contact" />

    </activity>
</application>
```

I am developing multiple buttons which open different activities but the contact one is just receiving this error.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your issue is:

```
<activity
    android:name=".contact"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
    <intent-filter> <!-- This is the error  -->
         <action android:name="saintbedeslytham.saintbedes.contact" />
                    <!-- It needs a closing tag for intent-filter here  -->
</activity>
```

What you need is another `</intent-filter>` before the `</activity>` tag.

Comment: It seems I need to wait "12 minutes" to mark this question right so don't worry if it isn't done straight away.